# How can I prevent my elements to overflow the screen in TV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, iptv

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="index">
        <div v-if="channel.ChName">
          <img
            :src="'http://uyanik.tv/conf/images/'+channel.Image"
            :class="{selectedIndex:currentIndex === index}"
            :ref="index"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.selectedIndex {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: aquamarine;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  /*flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*min-width:1200px;
  overflow-x:auto;      */
  justify-content: center;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 1 32.7%;
}
div > div > div > div > img{
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
div{
  text-align: center;
}
div > div > div{
  width:100%;
  padding:0 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 1 38.7%;
}
}
</style>
```

Here is my style and template. If I simply enable `flex-flow` and `wrapping`, it doesn't work as expected as items outflows to the outer screen. If I replace it with `block-inline` and some other CSS properties, it aligns as wrapped but runs too slowly. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: It is very hard to tell what the performance bottleneck on your TV is. TV browsers differ very much in capability and performance, and it really depends on what browser you are using on your TV. If you are looking into making a site or web application specifically for your TV browser, then I suggest you look into the web technologies it supports.

Comment: They are using Safari 5.38 and I have altered my code respect to that. I think problem has occurred because so many elements were fitting to the scree at the same time. We were afraid of using JS framework but that doesn't seem to be the case here.